# my form output is an object, but I wanna an array output

Tags: html, typescript

the output of my form is an object like this `{hourStart: '12', minuteStart: '10'}`
but I wanna an array output like this `[12,10]`

I have a form that this value is in form

here my html code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="time_field">
    <mat-label> minute </mat-label>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="minute_start" min="0" max="60">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="time_field">
    <mat-label> hour </mat-label>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="hour_start" min="0" max="24">
</mat-form-field>
```

here my typescript code:

```
onSubmit(): void {
   this.error$.next("");
   const body: ActuatorBody = this.form.value;
       body.id = this.data.element?.id;
       if (this.manualState && this.selectedTiming.value === 'manual') {
            body.manual_state = this.manualState.value;
       }
       this.setService.editActuator(body)
       .pipe(map((id: string) => id.toString()), take(1))
       .subscribe({
           next: (id: string) => {
                const auto = (this.data.element) ? this.data.element.automatic_state : false;
                const result: DialogResult<TableElement> = { message: "تنظیمات ذخیره شد.", succeed: true, data: this.createTableElement(id, body, auto) }
                    console.log(body);
                    this.close(result);
                 },
                 error: (err: any) => {
                     console.error(err);
                     this.error$.next(err.message);
                 }
            });
    }



private createTableElement(id: string, body: ActuatorBody, automatic_state: boolean) {
        const sections = body.sections.map((section) => section.number);
        return {
            id: id, name: body.name, organ_id: this.selectedOrgan,
            application_id: this.selectedApp.id, application_name: this.selectedApp.name,
            type_id: this.selectedType.id, type: this.selectedType.name,
            manual_state: body.manual_state ? body.manual_state : false,
            state_timing: { value: this.selectedTiming.value, name: this.selectedTiming.name },
            cronValues: { startHour: this.hourStart?.value, startMinute: this.minuteStart?.value },
            sections: sections
        }  as TableElement;
    }
```

I try some ways but they didn`t worked.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for what makes a [mre] and consider [edit]ing the code here to be one.  Ideally we can just paste it into our own IDEs to see the issue immediately and get to work on it, without dealing with unrelated problems like missing definitions. Excess code isn't great, but not enough code is also not good if we need to fix things you're not asking about.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

put your output in a const and use Object.values to convert an object to an array:

```
const output = {hourStart: '12', minuteStart: '10'}

Object.values(output)

// result => ['12', '10']
```